# Including Angular Files Out of Order - Providers

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-inject

I'd like to use gulp to inject my src files into html. I thought I could do this out of order as long as I included the module files first.

```
<script src="scripts/app.module.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/app.A.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.B.js"></script>
```

Here's what this would look like in plunkr-

http://plnkr.co/edit/KkJcbSzz5rTb7pvkYySB?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .provider('A', function(B) {
    this.$get = function() {};
  })
  .provider('B', function() {
    this.$get = function() {};
  });
```

But I get `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: B`

I understand the error but I thought this was something you could do. You can do it with services-

http://plnkr.co/edit/vfsjWMGQJr89HL93WyxS?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('A', function(B) {
    this.$get = function() {};
  })
  .service('B', function() {
    this.$get = function() {};
  });
```

Is it not possible to define things out of order with providers?